# How to add up values of a column when ranges have overlap in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this table:

```
    id   start  end  stg
0   ZZ   0      25   5.0
1   ZZ   10     65   7.0
2   ZZ   30     50   2.0
3   ZZ   50     60   3.0
4   BB   0      2    5.6
5   BB   5      8    6.6
6   BB   8      13   18.0
```

I want to add the values in "stg" if there are overlaps in ranges [start,end] and create new ranges and stg. The output should look something like this:

```
    id   start  end  stg
0   ZZ   0      10   5
1   ZZ   10     25   12
2   ZZ   25     30   7
3   ZZ   30     50   9
4   ZZ   50     60   10
5   ZZ   60     65   7
6   BB   0      5    5.6
7   BB   5      8    6.6
8   BB   8      13   18.0
```

Comment: I don't _think_ there's going to be a way to do this with broadcast (table-at-once) operations that will be any more efficient than just iterating. (Although maybe a Pandas wizard will come along and contradict that.) So just write the easy-to-understand explicit loop that would work for any sequence or iterable of intervals (or use an interval library off PyPI). If you get stuck, come back here with a specific question, of course, but it should be easy.

Comment: The problem is that I don't even know how to write that loop!

Comment: Could you post text instead of images? Also, I'm not sure the expected output DataFrame is totally accurate. The value 60 is missing from the expected output, and 75, 80, and 110 are not in the input.

Comment: @AntonvBR I have posted it as code. 
Peter, sorry you are right! I corrected the table (it can still have errors due to manual calculations) and I hope the idea is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a partial solution, since it ignores `id` completely. Using `IntervalIndex`:

#### Example data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['ZZ'] * 4, 
                   'start': [0, 10, 30, 50], 
                   'end': [25, 65, 50, 60], 
                   'stg': [5.0, 7.0, 2.0, 3.0]})
df = df[['id', 'start', 'end', 'stg']]

df
   id  start  end  stg
0  ZZ      0   25  5.0
1  ZZ     10   65  7.0
2  ZZ     30   50  2.0
3  ZZ     50   60  3.0
```

#### Get smallest subintervals defined by start and end values

```
subints = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks(sorted(np.unique(df[['start', 'end']].values.flatten())))
subints
IntervalIndex([(0, 10], (10, 25], (25, 30], (30, 50], (50, 60], (60, 65]]
              closed='right',
              dtype='interval[int64]')
```

#### Set an IntervalIndex on the original DF

```
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df['start'], df['end'])
df.set_index(idx, inplace=True)
df
          id  start  end  stg
(0, 25]   ZZ      0   25  5.0
(10, 65]  ZZ     10   65  7.0
(30, 50]  ZZ     30   50  2.0
(50, 60]  ZZ     50   60  3.0
```

#### Use IntervalIndex slicing in a list comprehension

```
result = pd.DataFrame([(s.left, s.right, df2.loc[s]['stg'].sum()) 
                       for s in subints], 
                      columns=['start', 'end', 'stg'])
result
   start  end   stg
0      0   10   5.0
1     10   25  12.0
2     25   30   7.0
3     30   50   9.0
4     50   60  10.0
5     60   65   7.0
```

Comment: Great! Just noticed a bug: one of the intervals is `(50, 50]`, which I'm guessing won't be helpful haha. Will edit a correction soon.

Comment: I can live with that ;-) Since I'm plotting these ranges, single points won't affect my results. But thanks in advance for fixing the code.

Comment: @geek2000, that's good to hear. Fixed, I think :P (added `np.unique`)